# How to Show Json resluts in Android with fast android networking library

Tags: java, android, json, xml, android-layout

I am using Fast Android Networking Library. Json response is working. I got the whole json string in logcat. How can I show a particular json object or string in textview or jsonarray in listview from this library. Please help, Thanks in Advance.

```
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

    try {
        json.put("email", loggedInUser);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.e("JSON", json.toString());

    AndroidNetworking.post(Constants.read_profile)
            .addBodyParameter("json", json.toString())
            .setTag("test")
            .setPriority(Priority.MEDIUM)
            .build()
            .getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener() {
                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.e("READ", response.toString());


                }

                @Override
                public void onError(ANError anError) {
                    Log.e("READ", anError.toString());
                }
            });
```

Comment: you can use gson library to parse json you got, use model class, set data to model class using gson, and get it back when you need.

Comment: Use this: https://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Comment: Paste your JSON Log

Answer (score 0):

Try GSON for json parsing. I am implementing the GSON code in your existing code.

Add this in app gradle
**implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'**

**For JSONObject Response**

```
getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener() {
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    @Override
    public void onResponse (JSONObject response){
        Log.e("READ", response.toString());

        if (response != null) {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Type type = new TypeToken<YourModelClass>() {
            }.getType();
            YourModelClass result = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), type);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onError (ANError anError){
        Log.e("READ", anError.toString());
    }
});
```

**For JSONArray Response**

```
@Override
public void onResponse (JSONArray response){
    Log.e("READ", response.toString());

    if (response != null) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type type = new TypeToken<List<YourModelClass>>() {
        }.getType();
        List<YourModelClass> result = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), type);
    }
}
```